# WriteBytes write String in my file

Tags: java, string, file, byte

Got a little problem than I can't understand. I have a String and I want to write it into byte in a file .txt (for test). Here is my code:

```
// Check writeVarString, writing in checkVarString.txt to verify 
fos = new FileOutputStream(pathCheckFile + "//checkVarString.txt");
dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

VarInt.writeVarString("Test number  1 for function writeVarString()", dos);
```

Here is my function writeVarString():

```
public static void writeVarString(String value, DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    try {
        int valueLength = value.length();

        if (valueLength > 0) {
            out.writeBytes(value);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Ok, it should work. Then I start my app and when I open my test file I got this:

> Test number  1 for function writeVarString()

Why I get a readable String? I should got bytes.
I already try to use with byte[] array = value.getBytes() then use out.write(array) but got same result.

Comment: Those are bytes in your file. Your file reader (Notepad?) is interpreting them as printable characters.

Comment: "Why I get a readable String? I should got bytes" - what do you think the difference is? What precise bytes did you expect vs what you got? How are you examining the content of the file?

Comment: @nicomp I open the file .txt from JDeveloper

Comment: @JonSkeet Well, I tried to do byte[] ar = value.getBytes(). And when I display byte to byte, I get number (as expected) and not a readable string.

Comment: @JonSkeet Get this precisely, my array of byte: 84,101,115,116,32,110,117,109,-23,114,111,32,49,32,112,111,117,114,32,108,97,32,102,111,110,99,116,105,111,110,32,119,114,105,116,101,86,97,114,83,116,114,105,110,103,40,41

Comment: It's still *really* unclear what you expect to be in the file. Do you mean you want the *text representation of each byte as a number*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it correctly. What's written in the file is bytes. In fact anything you write to a file will always be bytes.

However when you read the file, the application (text editor, cat command etc) will always try to interpret the file as text.

So your sollution is correct, it's just that you can't **see** the raw bytes as such.

Comment: Oh! It's why I didn't understand, because I didn't see the byte directly (as number). I totally forget that the text editor will directly interpret that. So, thanks you very much for this explanation!

Answer (score 3):

Because every character stored as byte in files. Your text editor read bytes and match them with char using fonts. Also there is encoding mechanism exists for string operation. You can use hex editors or plugin for looking byte/hex represents.

Comment: yeah, Gorazd explain the same thing. Thanks you very much, both of you gave me the light!

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the writeBytes documentations:

> void java.io.DataOutputStream.writeBytes(String s) throws IOException
>
> Writes out the string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits. If no exception is thrown, the counter written is incremented by the length of s.

Note that it writes " string to the underlying output stream as a sequence of bytes", and every character/integer/short/long is a sequence of bytes( which itself is a sequence of bits). So it is just the basic computer science knowledge.

Comment: hum... I knew that. I'm just asking myself why it was displayed as String and not as **raw** byte you know. In fact, it's wrote in raw byte but the text editor interpret as readable if it can interpret. My question was about the displaying, not the functionment.